# Unable to use windows.h ReadFile correctly on COM port. WriteFile seems to work fine

Tags: c++, windows, serial-port, readfile

I am trying to use the windows.h library to communicate through RS232 with a device (SCPI communication). I have looked at several tutorials and guides on how to set this up and think my code should work correctly. I am able to send data to the device using WriteFile. However, I am not able to receive any data using ReadFile (ReadFile generates no errors but the buffer size is 0). Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

void main ()
{
  // CreateFile
  HANDLE rs232 = CreateFileA ("\\\\.\\COM1", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);
  if (rs232 == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
  {
    printf ("fail CreateFile: %d\n", GetLastError ()); system ("pause"); return;
  }

  // Get & Set CommState
  DCB port_configuration;
  int err = GetCommState (rs232, &port_configuration);
  if (err <= 0)
  {
    printf ("fail GetCommState: %d\n", GetLastError ()); CloseHandle (rs232); system ("pause"); return;
  }
  port_configuration.BaudRate = 19200;
  port_configuration.ByteSize = 8;
  port_configuration.Parity = 0;
  port_configuration.StopBits = 0;
  port_configuration.DCBlength = sizeof (port_configuration);
  err = SetCommState (rs232, &port_configuration);
  if (err <= 0)
  {
    printf ("fail SetCommState\n"); CloseHandle (rs232); system ("pause"); return;
  }

  // SetCommTimeouts
  COMMTIMEOUTS timeout_configuration;
  timeout_configuration.ReadIntervalTimeout = 1;// MAXDWORD;
  timeout_configuration.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 1;// 0;
  timeout_configuration.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = 1;// 0;
  timeout_configuration.WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 1;// 0;
  timeout_configuration.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant = 1;// 0;
  err = SetCommTimeouts (rs232, &timeout_configuration);
  if (err <= 0)
  {
    printf ("fail SetCommTimeouts: %d\n", GetLastError ()); CloseHandle (rs232); system ("pause"); return;
  }

  // WriteFile
  DWORD buffer_size_w;
  char buffer_w[128] = "*IDN?\n";
  err = WriteFile (rs232, buffer_w, strlen (buffer_w), &buffer_size_w, 0);
  if (err <= 0)
  {
    printf ("fail WriteFile: %d\n", GetLastError ()); CloseHandle (rs232); system ("pause"); return;
  }
  printf ("written %d characters: %s\n", buffer_size_w, buffer_w);

  // ReadFile
  for (int x = 0; x < 10; ++x)
  {
    DWORD buffer_size_r;
    char buffer_r[128] = {0};
    err = ReadFile (rs232, buffer_r, 128, &buffer_size_r, 0);
    if (err <= 0)
    {
      printf ("fail ReadFile: %d\n", GetLastError ()); Sleep (250); continue;
    }
    printf ("read %d characters: %s\n", buffer_size_r, buffer_r);
    Sleep (250);
  }

  CloseHandle (rs232);
  system ("pause");
}
```

Here is some more information about my setup:

- I am using Windows 7 x64 and Microsoft Visual Studio 2013
- The project is compiled as a Win32 Console
- I use a FTDI Chipi-X USB to COM port converter cable
- I have tried connecting with a Newport Motion Controller and a Thorlabs Piezo Controller

Here are the things I have tried so far:

1. Update the drivers of the Chipi-X VCOM
2. Change the COMMTIMEOUTS to various different values as seen in guides online
3. Using a HyperTerminal I am able to fully communicate back and forth with the device. If I use my own program to send commands that request something of the device, such as "*IDN?\n", my own ReadFile would thus return nothing. However, when I connect the HyperTerminal again I can press ENTER to receive the requested information.
4. Change the buffer sizes using SetupComm()
5. Change the ReadFile buffer size to 1 byte at a time
6. Implement the OVERLAPPED method as explained in this guide: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff802693.aspx. It gave exactly the same problem as the non-overlapped code above: The windows functions would not generate errors but the read buffer would stay empty.
7. I tried communicating with a different device, this was interesting: Again I was able to fully communicate back and forth using the HyperTerminal. Whenever I used my own program to send, I would always receive the exact string I sent back using ReadFile. And again the actual requested information could be retrieved by reconnecting the HyperTerminal.

It seems to me there is some problem with buffers but I don't know what. I am also not sure if it is expectable that the HyperTerminal is able to pick up requested information that was requested several seconds earlier through a different COM port connection. Presumably the problem is related to my coding since the HyperTerminal works fine, but I cannot seem to find what is wrong with my code if I compare it with other code I find online.

Can someone help me out here?

EDIT:

8. I have created a new CLR/C++ test application using the following example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport(v=vs.110).aspx. This again gives the exact same problem of not being able to receive requests.
9. I have tried a Roline USB to RS232 cable: HyperTerminal works and my programming does not. The underlying hardware or drivers are likely not the problem here.

Comment: Your timeouts are entirely too short.  Don't ignore the handshake configuration in the DCB.  First make it work with another program like Putty or Hyperterminal so you can be sure that the device and the cable are functional.  If necessary use a serial port monitor program like PortMon to reproduce the exact same DCB.

Comment: I have tried with longer timeouts but it gave the same problems. I set them short now because I use the ReadFile in a for-loop (that has its own sleeps of 250 ms). As I already posted, I have used HyperTerminal and that worked fine. Also, when I then connect using my own program and use GetCommState it should give me the exact same handshake configuration that was used in the HyperTerminal.
I have just now tried different handshake configurations but that didn't solve it.
I tried using PortMon but it does not run on Windows 7 x64, not even with compatibility modes changed.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue:

I forgot to send the carriage return (\r) at the end of my commands. Apparently the devices I was testing with both were waiting for the combination \r\n before actually parsing the request.
Somehow by using the hyperterminal I would be able to append the \r\n to the current COM port output buffer and get results delayed like that.